# Why does the date only shows up but not the time in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, to-date, to-char, sql-timestamp

I've inserted a record into reserve table like this:

```
INSERT INTO reserve(garage_code, vunit_id, reserve_date_time_placed, renter_no)
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT vehicle_unit.garage_code, vehicle_unit.vunit_id
FROM vehicle_unit 
INNER JOIN garage ON vehicle_unit.garage_code=garage.garage_code
WHERE vehicle_insurance_id ='sports-ute-449-12b' AND garage_name= 'Melbourne Central VIC'),
(SELECT TO_DATE('2019/05/04 04:00 PM', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh:mi AM') FROM dual),
(SELECT renter_no FROM RENTER WHERE renter_fname='Van' AND renter_lname='DIESEL');
```

However, only the specified dates shows up but not the time. I tried

```
(SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2019/05/04 04:00 PM', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh:mi AM'), 'yyyy/mm/dd hh:mi AM') FROM dual)
```

But it returns error 'invalid string literal'?

Comment: I haven't read your main question, but I can explain what's happening in your example at the end. You have a digit `0` instead of capital letter `O` in `TO_DATE`; that is a typo that is easily corrected, then you'll see the correct output.  ...And actually upon further inspection, you have the same in the main question!

Comment: Sorry was editing my code and accidentally put the 0.Anyway, the error still stands even if it is a capital o.

Comment: Another thing that stands out - you have an inner join between `vehicle_unit` and `garage`, and then what appears to be an intended cross join to two small  subqueries. Except that for the inner join you use the ANSI syntax ("inner join") but for the other joins you use comma syntax. I don't know if this is a direct violation of correct syntax, but even if it isn't, it's going to lead to bugs and unintended behavior. Instead of comma, put `cross join` in the `FROM` clause and see if that cures the problem.

Comment: And, the reason you don't see the time component (once the query is running) is that you select a date. How the date is **displayed** depends on your NLS settings. For example, issue the following command BEFORE running your query: `alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy/mm/dd hh:mi AM'` and then run the query, see what happens. If you are using a graphical interface, like SQL Developer or Toad, find where you can set the format for dates; this is always an issue on the *client* side, there's nothing wrong with the query!

Comment: That solved my problem.Thanks!